# Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 GT-N8020 not showing up on Google Play Store Developer Console's device list

Tags: android, google-play, galaxy

We have developed an application with very few device limitations. I fact, it should be only limited by Android version (requires Android 2.2.x, API level 8).
However, I just got my hands on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 GT-N8020. I can't find our app on the Play Store on that device. When I look at the list of supported devices in the Play Store Developer Console, there is no such device GT-N8020.
There are, however, dozens of other Galaxy Notes 10.1. None of them shows a GT-N**** model name.
Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with the GT-N8020?

On a side-note: Google states that, if a device is not listed, you should contact them. Following the link there is just a FAQ and absolutely no way to get in touch with a real person whatsoever:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/136601

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

The 'ironic' (or panic) thing is I have 2 very similar app on the store (basically one is the light version of the other). 
The lighter is available and says 1582 compatible devices, the bigger is not visible with 1487 devices. BUT ALSO IN 1582 DEVICE LIST THERE IS NO GALAXY GT-N8020!!!!

The only difference in the manifest are the permissions for the GPS

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

everithing else is identical (also 80% of the code).

Can't really understand!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in fact my previous "answer" was not a real one, rather the extention of the qustion.

Here are my answer at least to my probleblem with Note II:

My Project's targetSDKversion and maxSDKversion was set to API level 14, so of course it was not listed on Note II with API level 16.

It is a terrible mistake on my side, but maybe worth for checking, as it is not unpossible to change the values unintended....

The maxSDKversion alone limits the devices, so even if targetSDKversion is set to 17, but the maxSDKversion set to 14, the app is not listed on devices with API level 15 and higher.

Furthermore, using this value is not recommended regarding the developer documentation.

Of course this is not an explanation why the devices in question does not appear as a device in developer console...

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately the same with GT-N7105 Galaxy Note II...
It is not at all listed as a device ....

I just wondering, how it is possible to download any application (except our own....) if the device is not exist?

This is very strange and as Stefano said, panic.....